# webkit : how to get the actual content of a page after content was added via javascript?

Tags: webkit, vala

I want to get the actual content of a page I loaded into a webview after some content has been updated by some jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#main").append('<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>');
});
```

After the page has been updated I tried to get the content of page with the following command [vala syntax]

```
web_view.get_main_frame ().get_data_source().get_data().str
```

but I only get the original content (even if loading is finished)

using

```
web_view.get_dom_document().document_element.text_content
```

I get the actual content but the tags are removed.

I guess I could walk the whole tree to get the actual document but tere should be a more easy way to do it.

EDIT:
my solution

```
this.web_view.load_finished.connect ((source, frame) => {
 stderr.printf(this.web_view.get_dom_document().body.get_inner_html());
}
```

I'll probably find this awfull when I'll read this some years from now but for now I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML DOM, elements implement the HTMLElement interface. The [HTMLElement interface in WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLElement.idl) includes the [outerHTML](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLElement.idl#L45) property. This property returns a string containing the serialized markup of the element and all of its children. I'm not familiar with Vala but based on your code snippets this would be accessed like so:

```
web_view.get_dom_document().document_element.outer_html
```

Comment: Yep. This should be something like that. My problem is with vala syntax/bindings. I can't find any  HTMLElementInterface in inheritance tree http://valadoc.org/#!api=webkit-1.0/WebKit.DOMElement

Comment: edit: this is the other way around (http://valadoc.org/#!api=webkit-1.0/WebKit.DOMHTMLElement) the htmlElement is above the domelement and i don't know how to get an htmlelement from a webview (or from webview.dom_document). Yes total newB inside ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer in Vala is this:

```
webview.get_dom_document().get_body().get_inner_html ()
```